# USA-Philippines flight via Toronto with US J1 visa

Tags: visas, usa, canada, filipino-citizens, j1-visas

I am a J1 Visa holder of the United States and a Philippines passport holder. I have a layover flight of 22 hours at Toronto Canada. Will I be able to go out at the airport and look around and meet my cousin if I have a valid ticket going back to my country - the Philippines.

How does it work with my luggage? Do I need to check out my luggage or it will send directly to my next flight?

Comment: So the flight is from the US to the Philippines, or the other way?

Comment: Do i still need a transit visa to go out the airport. Or can i just meet my cousin somewhere in the airport?

Comment: Yes. From US to Philippines. Layover at Toronto? --jjb

Comment: Related questions: http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/4598/canadian-visa-rules-for-flight-connections and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/22394/travelling-from-us-to-sri-lanka-do-i-need-transit-visa-for-canada/22400 Going to or from the Philippines is a special case so I don't know exactly how it works.

Comment: Regarding luggage, see http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/14423/transferring-luggage-when-taking-another-plane http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights?rq=1 and http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/18724/will-i-have-to-pick-up-my-luggage-and-recheck-it-if-i-have-booked-a-connection-w

Answer (score 4):

According the website, if you want to benefit from the [Transit without visa program](http://www.cic.gc.ca/english/department/twov/travellers.asp) (assuming it's possible for your flight), you should, among other things

> proceed to the CBSA area for clearance or remain in an isolated transit area while waiting for a connecting flight (passengers that leave the isolated transit area must go to the CBSA area for examination)

To get clearance to leave the isolated area and in all other cases, I assume that you would have to follow the general rules, which for a citizen of the Philippines probably means that you need a visa. At least, being in transit or having a ticket to go elsewhere would *not* automatically exempt you from this requirement. Note that it also means that transit through Canada often requires a visa, *even if you don't want to leave the airport*.

As TWOV is a special program, you should probably try to check with the airline if you are eligible or not in any case.