# Will airlines object to me booking separate "legs" of the same journey individually?

Tags: air-travel, legal, tickets

I want to purchase a separate ticket from San Francisco to New York and then fly from New York on the same day with a separate ticket to Germany.  I can save money by doing this but do not know if airlines allow this. I'm interested in answers for relevant for both legs on a single airline, or on separate airlines.

Comment: Who can stop you from buying 2 tickets? The airlines don't care

Comment: Your question title implies you want to know whether it'll be cheaper or not, whereas your question body implies that you want to know whether it's allowed. **Yes**, no airline can stop you from doing that.

Comment: Someone else edited my title.  I was not asking if it is cheaper, I was asking if there was some sort of restriction to do this.  Somewhere in my past travels I thought this wasn't allowed by airlines, but it may have been a Southwest issue in Texas.  Thank you for the responses.

Comment: More information would be useful. are the two "legs" booked with the same airline or two different airlines. While technically this is no business of the airlines, some may TRY to stop you doing so if they lose $ as a result. If yu make two bookings yourself and miss the second flight due to eg delays on the first one, the 2nd journey airline may charge you for the missed flight. If you book via an agent as a single journey with two "legs" this should not be an issue, but ask.

Comment: @AnkurBanerjee The question is perfectly clesar. I edited the subject line as it had been edited wrongly and the meaning had been destroyed.

Comment: Have you thought about what would happen if your first flight is delayed? If you're on two different tickets, then airline #2 would just cancel your ticket as a no-show, since you wouldn't be there and they wouldn't know why...

Comment: @RussellMcMahon: I'm afriad your question isn't perfectly clear. It's still uncertain whether you mean on a single airline, or multiple airlines.  Although the answer is probably the same: How would they try to stop you?

Comment: @Flimzy - I agree re  1 airline or 2 - and I asked for clarification re that in my question above. But, the question covers either case. | My daughter had a multi leg flight (around the world) valid over a year. It included say ...-Dublin-Munich- ... . She flew Dublin to Amsterdam in another airline and advised the main trip airline (Lufthansa) of this prior to the Dublin-Munich leg  - they saved on the deal as they had a paid but unused seat. *BUT* they consequently cancelled the whole of the rest of the ticket. All unused legs. Notionally the fine print allows them to do so. ...

Comment: ... Needless to say my daughter managed to get the other legs reinstated BUT that is what airlines can do, or try to do. The extra flight was not related to them and they were notified in advance and they saved money - and, no, our family will not be flying Lufthansa every again in this lifetime if at all possible.

Answer (score 11):

How exactly would they "not allow" this? What do you imagine they could legally do to prevent it?

However, it usually has severe disadvantages for you:

- In most cases it will be more expensive (assuming both legs are the same airline). It's VERY rare for two separate tickets to cost less than a combined one; in fact in many cases the combined ticket will be cheaper than than the longer leg on its own.
- It may not be possible to check through your baggage, and then you'll have to collect it and check it in again, which can take a lot of time
- If you miss the second flight because of that or because the first one is delayed, you will have to pay for another ticket

Comment: I disagree with your point about the price always being higher for separate tickets. This varies a lot and depends heavily on what route you are traveling. The other two points are, however, spot on.

Comment: @Kris if the two legs are operated by same airlines then what michael said is true.,,

Comment: What they could do is presumably what American Airlines did to get rid of lifetime passes: Find you in breach of some clause in the contract/general condition of carriage. Not that it seems very likely or worth their trouble but the question does not seem particularly unreasonable. +1 for the disadvantages.

Comment: Perhaps you meant your first point to apply only to flights on the same airline, in which case it may well be true. I have edited the answer to make this clear--I hope that's within the intent of your answer. If not, feel free to roll-back or modify my edit.

Answer (score 4):

I did it once many years ago with a low cost airline that only sells point-to-point tickets (like Southwest but in Europe). As others already mentioned, the downside is that you cannot expect any help from them if you miss the connection (i.e. you might lose the money you spent for the second leg *and* have to buy another ticket at a premium on the spot or at least pay some extra fee to change the ticket; in the worse case, the return journey for the second leg might be invalidated as well).

Since I also had to collect my luggage and drop it off, go through a passport and security check again (low-cost carriers typically don't offer any connection), it was all really tight even though I had *several hours* between the flights. That's the reason why you might come across language that strongly discourages it but beyond that, I don't think airlines really care.

Note that some airlines might require you to claim your luggage as a matter of policy but strictly speaking it's not always necessary *even if you don't have a single booking for the whole trip*, see [Can I through check my bags on separate bookings (international flights)?](https://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights) With a bit of luck it could all go very smoothly – but personally, I still wouldn't risk it.

Another issue that hasn't been mentioned yet is that if you want to benefit from a transit exemption in a country for which you would otherwise need a visa, it might be impossible to collect your luggage and remain airside without the airline's assistance (that's not relevant in the US but that's something to keep in mind for other people considering a similar trip elsewhere). Worse case here is that you could be refused boarding on the first leg because you don't have a visa for the destination (that's what happened to the person who posted the earlier question).

Comment: Thanks for your perspectives, insight, and opinions.  Based upon all of those aspects, I will be booking a round trip flight and not take my chances.  Happy Holidays!!!

Answer (score 1):

From the airline’s point of view:

1. They are selling you a ticket SFO–New York
2. They are selling you another ticket New York–Germany

The first ticket obliges them to get you to New York from San Francisco and back. The second ticket obliges them to get you to Germany from New York and back. Both tickets come with a significant caveat: you have to present yourself at check-in/the gate on time for each individual leg on each ticket.

From your point of view:

1. You get a ticket SFO–Germany, *but*
2. You need to make sure your bags (if any) are transferred to the transatlantic flight in New York (usually exit the security area, pick up and recheck)
3. You need to be in New York with ample time to do that (an issue for both directions)
4. If you miss the connection due to a flight being late you are counted as a no-show on the second

   - If you no-show on the New York–Germany leg, you lose the Germany–New York leg (but you can have a holiday in New York instead)
5. You will extremely likely need to have a longer connection time at New York, your duty free goods bought in Germany will have to make it into your luggage in New York and your entire trip may be more expensive; give or take a few minor inconveniences.

   (For the record, the return trip doesn’t make that much of a difference since you would need to clear customs and immigration in New York anyway.)

The airline probably would have gotten money for the New York–Germany leg this way or that. As you are in San Francisco, they are now happy that they can get additional money from you for SFO–New York – money that could otherwise have gone to a competitor, low cost airline, petrol stations or Amtrack, in theory. Furthermore, they have little to no additional risk because the missed-connection risk is entirely yours. I struggle to find a reason why they would disallow it, even if the prices are strongly in your favour.

Answer (score 0):

I'm looking at a flight from Salt Lake City, Utah to Sydney, Australia. On Delta, it costs $1215 for a round trip flight that goes through LAX. However, the same round-trip flight to LAX is $168, and the same roundtrip flight from LAX to SYD is $718. So booking the **exact same flights**, on the same airline, costs $886 instead of $1215. I have no idea why Delta charges so much for the international round trip from SLC, but this is very commonly the case.

In this case, I'll book them separately to save money, but if my connection is messed up, it's the same airline, so there's a decent chance they'll take care of me.

When I've done this on separate airlines, I've made sure that there's plenty of time between my first flight and the connection so that if something goes wrong on the first flight, there's time to catch another connection (even if I have to go buy it from someone else) in order to not miss the big, expensive flight.

Comment: I don’t know what your definition of ‘decent’ is, but if it is or includes ‘zero’ then [yes you have a ‘decent’ chance of them taking care of you](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/137599).

Comment: On the topic of the cost difference: Checking Google Flights for SLC–LAX it seems that Delta is the only major carrier flying directly to SLC from LAX. United and American do not (apparantly) directly fly there, they only use the services of another airline. On the other hand, all three *and* Qantas *and* Virgin Australia fly LAX–SYD as that is a major hub to hub route. So Delta can charge a higher price from SLC because there is less competition from there to anywhere outside but needs to be more price competitive from the major hub LAX to Sydney.