# Travelling from Delhi to Dubai to Istanbul (Turkey), staying at Dubai airport only for 7 hours: Do I need a visa for transit at airport?

Tags: visas, transit, luggage, airport-transfer, dubai

1. I am travelling from Delhi to Dubai via Air India on 22.05.2014 and will land in Dubai at 22:45 pm.
2. next flight from Dubai to Istanbul (turkey) via Turkish Airlines on 23.05.2014 at 5:40 am (after 7 hours).
3. I have booked both flight on my own, separately, hence technically they are not connecting flights.
4. I will not be leaving airport. I do not have a visa for Dubai but I do have a visa for Turkey.

Could you please confirm the following:

1. Will I get "ok to board" confirmation on Delhi airport (India) for travelling to Dubai (UAE) without a Dubai visa?
2. Do I need a visa to stay at Dubai airport?
3. I will have luggage, how do I collect my luggage at Dubai airport for onward journey to Turkey without going through passport control?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Can I through check my bags on separate bookings (international flights)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights)

Comment: And you are a citizen of which country?

Answer (score 2):

No.

*I am assuming you are an Indian citizen, holding only an Indian passport.*

You cannot collect baggage without a visa, as the baggage claim is *after* immigration.

You also cannot get a boarding pass without checking in on your Turkish airlines flight at India. To do this, you would have to leave the transit area in Dubai and then enter again at Terminal 2.

You do not need a visa to transit through Dubai International Airport, unfortunately in your case you are not a transit passenger. You have a point-to-point journey.

If you are granted a boarding pass from India, you would have to exit Dubai, and to do this you can get a 96 hour transit visa assuming you have valid documents proving your journey. You will also need your passport to be 6 months current and have at minimum two empty pages.

The good news is that 7 hours is plenty of time to get all this done.

Answer (score 1):

The answers are yes, no, depends on the airport.  I have never been on this particular route, but by international agreement airports let transitioning passengers *stay in the airport* until their next flight.  Do not try to leave the airport, you need a visa for that.

Your third question is the tricky one.  You may (but maybe not) need to pick up your bags and drop them off at the next flight.  Every airport is different but you will not need a visa to do this.  Ask a flight attendant for help if you find yourself confused.  7 hours should be more than enough time to figure it out.

Comment: That isn't universally true about "by international agreement" - some countries require airside transiting passengers of some nationalities to have visas even for airside transit, and some countries (eg USA) never offer airside transit