# Is Dubai visa required to get luggage for an Egyptian citizen?

Tags: visas, dubai, egyptian-citizens

I am Egyptian living in Cairo and I am planning my honeymoon in the Philippines. I booked 2 different flights that are not connected.

One flight will be Cairo to Dubai on Qatar airways then the next day is Dubai to Manila on Cebu Pacific. My plan was to stay in Dubai airport hotel or something until my Cebu Pacific flight. My question is do I need a visa to Dubai?

I know that Egyptians in general need visas. But in my case since I am not leaving the airport do I still need a visa in order to get my luggage? I hope I get an answer I really don't want to face any problems in my honeymoon.

Comment: So you plan on spending the night in the airport? How many hours between flights?

Comment: Related: [Can I through check my bags on separate bookings (international flights)?](http://travel.stackexchange.com/questions/2173/can-i-through-check-my-bags-on-separate-bookings-international-flights/2183#2183) (Covers changing between two tickets in Dubai with luggage)

Answer (score 2):

Short Answer: **You need a visa**.

---

I don't think you'll be able to start your journey as the Qatar Airways check-in counter will refuse to give you a boarding pass because your flight is to Dubai and you do not have documentation showing that you can enter Dubai.

Assuming somehow that you are able to get a boarding pass and check-in your luggage; your journey is strictly to Dubai - this includes your baggage.

In order to continue your journey, you will have to collect your bags; go to the check-in counter; re-check your bags; collect your boarding pass and then go through security and customs - just as if you were starting your journey in Dubai.  All this requires a visa to enter Dubai.

You have one thing going for you - if you can show the forward ticket and speak to the customs officer, they might give you a transit visa *but this depends on the time between your flights*.

If its a short transit then you might have a difficult case; however the customs officers are quite friendly and if you explain your case you might get an exception - **but do not rely on this.**

The best way to guarantee your honeymoon isn't cut short:

1. Depending on the time between your flights; you can choose to book a night at a hotel in Dubai and have them arrange a visa for you.
2. Reschedule your flights so that you are on one carrier (or codeshare flight); this way your baggage will be checked through till your final destination.

Comment: There's a (not free) [Meet and Greet Transfer Service](http://www.marhabaservices.com/english/our-services/meet-greet) offered at Dubai, where they'll take your baggage tags, collect and recheck for you if you can't clear immigration, which could help too

Comment: If I am not mistaken in this case the person should already have onward boarding pass afaik (otherwise, the luggage cannot be checked in); but its worth an inquiry email.