# Can Israelis recheck luggage in Dubai?

Tags: transit, luggage, dubai, israeli-citizens

I have a ticket with a connection in Dubai, in which I will be transferred to a different airline. Recheck of checked baggage is needed. Is this possible with an Israeli passport?

In my specific case the airlines are Pegasus (arriving) and IndiGo (departing) - 2 separate tickets.

Comment: Which are the two airlines involved, and did you purchase both flights together (ie, on one "ticket") or separately?

Comment: Pegasus (arriving) and IndiGo (departing) - 2 separate tickets. see edit

Comment: Definitely not going to work. I hope your tickets are fully refundable, or you've lost some money.

Answer (score 8):

I don't think you can travel on your proposed itinerary.

Entry to the UAE is not permitted for Israeli passport holders. You can only transit airside if you are traveling with an Israeli passport and have no other passport.

If you attempt to board the first flight, the airline will tell you that a visa is required or that you will be refused entry to the UAE, and will [deny boarding](https://travel.stackexchange.com/q/2173/3221) on that basis.

If you have a passport from some other country, you may be able to use it to transit landside.

You might be able to pay [marhaba](http://www.marhabaservices.com/) to transfer your bags for you, but that doesn't eliminate the problem of being denied boarding in the first place.

If the two airlines have a baggage interlining agreement (almost, but not quite the same as, being in the same alliance), you *may* be able to convince the check-in agent to through-check the bags. He or she may be unwilling or unable to do this, though, when you have separate tickets.

If you want to be assured of making this connection, you should buy the entire itinerary on a single ticket, rather than separate tickets. In this case, the airline will through-check your bags (with very rare exceptions). If you actually did buy a single ticket, you may be confused and think you need to transfer your bags yourself, when you actually don't. Check with the ticketing airline in this case to find out what will happen.

Comment: This answer may be right, but it may also be completely wrong.  It's impossible to answer without knowing the details of which airline and whether it's one ticket or two.

Comment: @Doc Eh? This answer covers both scenarios. I don't understand your comment.

Comment: Yes, about 5 paragraphs in after you've already said No about 3 times.  And interline agreements are nothing like "being in the same alliance"

Comment: @Doc PC and 6E do not have a baggage interline agreement. Even on one ticket, the bags cannot be through checked. (Moreover 6E does not appear to interline with anyone on bags or ticketing, perhaps because they are a point-to-point carrier.) (But I agree that baggage interline agreements and alliances are unrelated.)